# Hide label on slice of Doghnut/Pie Chart Angular ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have started using ng2-charts with Angular where I need to hide the text/value coming on slice of doughnut/Pie chart as shown and highlighted in below screenshot

[image]
Below is my code

```
pieChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips:{
          callbacks: {
            label: (ttItem,data) => (`${data.labels[ttItem.index]}: ${data.datasets[ttItem.datasetIndex].data[ttItem.index]}%`)
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          display:false,
          // labels: {
          //   // render: 'percentage',
          //   // fontColor: ['red', 'red', 'red'],
          //   // precision: 2,
          //   display:false
          // },
          datalabels: false ,
          label:false,
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          labels: {
            fontColor: "black",
            boxWidth: 15,
            padding: 10,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins ',
            fontSize: 12,
          },  
        },
        animation: {
          animateScale: true,
          animateRotate: true
        }
    };
    isPieChartPercentage :boolean = true;
    pieChartColors = [
        {
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(144, 238, 144)',
            '#ADD8E6',
            '#ffff80',
            '#e0eafc',
            '#f0b961',
            'black'
          ]
        }
    
      ]
```

I tried this things which didn't worked for me

```
options: {
  datalabels: {
    display: false, //not working
  },
}
```

```
options: {
  labels: {
    display: false // not working
  },
}
```

```
options: {
  labels:false  //not working
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are probably using another plugin as the datalabels plugin so you will need to disable it under a different naming space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are trying to remove the label from your chart i.e is from the pie of your chart. So to inform you if you don't know that label is coming from **"chartjs-plugin-labels"**

Either you can remove it, if not you can try below solution

```
     plugins: {
          labels: {
            render: function (args) {
              return   "";
            },
            fontColor: ['black', 'black', 'black'],
            precision: 2,
          }
        },
```